# Drupal 7 programmatically call hook function from different module

Tags: php, function, module, drupal-7, call

How do I call a hook function in a separate file from mymodule.module?

Using **Features** and **Node Export**, there is array data returned from a  **hook_node_export_features_default** function. I want to retrieve that array data in the .module file of the same module but when I try calling the function directly:

```
$data = mymodule_node_export_features_default();
dsm($data, 'Import Data');
```

I get the following error

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function

How can I call such a function successfully?

Answer (score 1):

```
module_invoke_all();
```

should do the trick to call hooks : 
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_invoke_all/7

if you to call a particular function, you'll need to include the module file that contains this function.

```
module_load_include('module', 'mymodule'); $data = mymodule_node_export_features_default(); 
dsm($data, 'Import Data');
```

Comment: Thanks jde. I tried module_invoke_all before but it doesn't return the array from the hook function. I got the same, no data, result trying a different hook. The hook function is in the same module but in a different file

Comment: Try this https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/function/module_load_include/7

module_load_include('module', 'mymodule');
$data = mymodule_node_export_features_default();
dsm($data, 'Import Data');

Comment: I'll put this in another answer ;)